# Required diameter for ballast drop hole?

Tags: civil-engineering, design

I'm currently an underground Geotechnical Engineer, don't spend a lot of time on the surface. I'm trying to find a reference or method for calculating the required diameter of a service hole. My Mine is looking to install a 600mm drop hole to transport ballast underground, and the ballast itself is up to 150mm. I don't believe this will be large enough and that at some stage it will become blocked, this is based on past experienced, but nothing more. I'm struggling to find a reference or method to back this up and to provide an alternative diameter. There are several "rules of thumb" from older Engineers, but no references to support them. Any help would be appreciated.